# How can I create a templated control with Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm trying to create a templated control with Asp.Net MVC. By templated control, I mean a control that accepts markup as input like so:

```
<% Html.PanelWithHeader()
    .HeaderTitle("My Header")
    .Content(() =>
    { %>
        <!-- ul used for no particular reason -->
        <ul>
          <li>A sample</li>
          <li>A second item</li>
        </ul>
    <% }).Render(); %>
```

Note: Yes, this is very similar to [how Telerik creates its MVC controls](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu/templates), I like the syntax.

Here's my PanelWithHeader code:

```
// Extend the HtmlHelper
public static PanelWithHeaderControl PanelWithHeader(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return new PanelWithHeaderControl();
}

public class PanelWithHeaderControl
{
    private string headerTitle;

    private Action getContentTemplateHandler;

    public PanelWithHeaderControl HeaderTitle(string headerTitle)
    {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;

        return this;
    }

    public PanelWithHeaderControl Content(Action getContentTemplateHandler)
    {
        this.getContentTemplateHandler = getContentTemplateHandler;

        return this;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        // display headerTitle as <div class="header">headerTitle</div>

        getContentTemplateHandler();
    }
}
```

This displays the `ul`, but I have no idea how to display custom code within my Render method.

I have tried using the HtmlHelper with no success. I have also tried overriding the ToString method to be able to use the `<%=Html.PanelWithHeader()...` syntax, but I kept having syntax errors.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [Telerik MVC extensions are open-source and available at CodePlex](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/) so I took a quick look at the source code.

They create an HtmlTextWriter from the ViewContext of the HtmlHelper instance. When they write to it, it writes to the page.

The code becomes:

```
// Extend the HtmlHelper
public static PanelWithHeaderControl PanelWithHeader(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    HtmlTextWriter writer = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.CreateHtmlTextWriter(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output);

    return new PanelWithHeaderControl(writer);
}

public class PanelWithHeaderControl
{
    private HtmlTextWriter writer;

    private string headerTitle;

    private Action getContentTemplateHandler;

    public PanelWithHeaderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public PanelWithHeaderControl HeaderTitle(string headerTitle)
    {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;

        return this;
    }

    public PanelWithHeaderControl Content(Action getContentTemplateHandler)
    {
        this.getContentTemplateHandler = getContentTemplateHandler;

        return this;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        writer.Write("<div class=\"panel-with-header\"><div class=\"header\">" + headerTitle + "</div><div class=\"content-template\">");

        getContentTemplateHandler();

        writer.Write("</div></div>");
    }
}
```

*I know, the code is a mess

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like `Html.BeginPanel()` / `Html.EndPanel()`, similar to how forms are created with `Html.BeginForm()` / `Html.EndForm()`.  This way you can wrap the contained content rather than need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: This would work, but its ugly and requires the user to remember to call both.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Render()
{
    Response.Write(getContentTemplateHandler());
}
```

Comment: The point being that, to get output from a `<% %>` without an equals sign, you have to Write to the Response object.