# How to write ASP.NET MVC Helper Extension that can take server html with %> ... <%

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

The problem I am facing today, I dont know the correct keyword to search in google.

Ok, I want to write a html helper extension method, say a very normal custom html extension method that will write the string in response as

```
<%= Html.MyCustomHtml("Hello World") %>
```

- I am expecting that this snippet will write

  Hello World

in the response. Well, I can do that as

```
public static string MyCustomHtml(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
{
   return "<span>" + text + "</span>  
}
```

But, I can see many commercial extensions (like Telerik) that can take server html so that I could use my Custom Extension as

```
<%= Html.MyCustomHtml(%>

  <span> Hurray! we made it</span>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>

<%) %>
```

Now, how can I make my custom html extension method so that this usage can be made possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822272/how-can-i-create-a-templated-control-with-asp-net-mvc